# Why is the image coming out blurry?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have the following image that I'm trying to display under my navigation bar.

[image: car]

The image dimensions are 234 x 156 px

For some reason, the image is coming out blurry and the entire image cannot be seen. Is it because it's too small to begin with in terms of height/width? or some other factor?

Here is the code snippet that displays the image:

```
 <div class="flex w-full justify-center">
          <img
              src="../images/cars.png" alt= ""
              class= "h-48 w-full object-cover" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h-48 w-full` classes set the size of the image box (the rendering area). This box will have a height of `12rem` (`192px`) and a width equal to its parent's.

In this box, `.object-cover` zooms the image in (or out, if original image size is larger than the box size), without changing pixel aspect ratio, to the minimum image size at which it covers the box entirely.

If the box's aspect ratio is equal to the image's, the image is not cropped. If it's not equal, the image is cropped on the axis on which it exceeds the box.

In your case, (guessing the width of the parent is fairly large - e.g: ~`1000 - 1200px`) the image is zoomed in until its width is equal to the box width and the excess is cropped (from top and bottom).

Which, most likely, makes the image pixelated, considering its enlarged 3-4 times (typically pixelation occurs above 2x original size).

Play with possible class combinations in the following demo:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, toRefs } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      fits: ['contain', 'cover', 'fill', 'none', 'scale-down'],
      currentFit: 'cover',
      widths: ['full', '72', '64', '48'],
      currentWidth: 'full',
      labelClass: 'cursor-pointer hover:text-blue-500',
      optionLabels: ['Description', 'Crops image', 'Stretches image', 'Box background visible'],
      options: {
        contain: ['Image contained in box', false, false, true],
        cover: ['Image covers box', true, false, false],
        fill: ['Image stretched to box size', false, true, false],
        none: ['Image displayed without any scaling (original size), regardless of box sizes', true, false, true],
        'scale-down': ['Same as -none except large images are scaled down to fit box', false, false, true]
      }
    })
    return toRefs(state)
  }
})
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.45/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="flex w-full justify-center bg-gray-100">
    <img
      src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PUa3.png"
      alt=""
      class="h-48 border bg-fuchsia-400"
      :class="{[`object-${currentFit}`]: true, [`w-${currentWidth}`]: true }"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="p-2 border-0 border-t border-zinc-200">
      <h2 class="font-bold text-xl">Object Fit:</h2>
      <label
        v-for="fit in fits"
        :key="fit"
        class="pr-2"
        :class="currentFit === fit ? '': labelClass"
      >
        <input type="radio" v-model="currentFit" :value="fit" />
        {{ `object-${fit}` }}
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2">
      <h2 class="font-bold text-xl">Width:</h2>
      <label
        v-for="width in widths"
        :key="width"
        class="pr-2"
        :class="currentWidth === width ? '': labelClass"
      >
        <input type="radio" v-model="currentWidth" :value="width" />
        {{ `w-${width}` }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-gray-100 pb-8 pt-2 border-0 border-t border-zinc-200">
    <div class="container mx-auto grid grid-cols-3">
      <div class="font-bold pl-2 text-xl text-right pr-4" v-text="`.object-${currentFit}`"></div>
      <div class="col-span-2"></div>
      <template v-for="(label, index) in optionLabels" :key="index">
        <h3 class="italic px-4 text-right" v-text="`${label}:`"></h3>
        <code v-text="options[currentFit][index]" class="col-span-2"></code>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- I've added short descriptions for each object fit option
- I've given the box a pink background and its parent a light grey background

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll try it out and let you know, fingers crossed

Answer (score 1):

Assume you're on tailwind.
Try a defined dimension

```
 <div class="flex w-full justify-center">
      <img
          src="../images/cars.png" alt= ""
          class= "h-48 w-72 object-cover" />
</div>
```

or object-contain

```
     <div class="flex w-full justify-center">
          <img
              src="../images/cars.png" alt= ""
              class= "h-48 w-full object-contain" />
    </div>
```

to narrow down the cause to css sizing instead of other issues

Comment: A note: Though for the purposes of this answer it's fine, I would *highly* recommend adding `alt` text, even during development - after all, if your website does not have `alt` text, many search engines will rate your page lower.

Comment: Thanks, tried both of your suggestions, but it still did not work. When I used the contain method the image was there, and it was clear but it was not the entire width of the top of the page. When I use the cover method the image is the entire width of the page, but it is blurry and the top and bottom of the image is cut off and you can only see the middle.

Comment: Both are expected behaviours as you've described. Any demo or screenshot to indicate what design/effect you're looking for?